# What is the best way to validate a List of JsonNodes against a Map of values?

Tags: java, java-stream, completable-future

I have a Map that holds a name and an ID for an object. From my service, I am getting a List where each JsonNode contains a name, and should contain an id. I want to use the Map (which is authoritative) to validate the id that corresponds to the name in the JsonNode. For example:

```
JsonNode  Map
Mark 23   Mark 23
Chris 43  Chris 43
Ralph 21  Ralph 31
```

In this case, the first two match, the last doesn't. I want to iterate through all the JsonNodes and the Map and collect all the the names where the node id doesn't match the Map id.

I can make it work with the following code:

```
// stream all the nodes, filter the nodes with either no "id" or with an id <> expected, 
// collect into a list.
nodes.stream().filter(r -> {
            String name = r.get("name").asText();
            if (r.has("id")) {
                Long nodeId = r.get("id").asText();
                Long expectedId = map.get(name);
                if (expectedId == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (nodeId != map.get(name)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else { //no id in node
                return true;
            }
        }).map(r-> r.get("$id").asText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There will be no more than 2000 JsonNodes in the list, usually much less (< 100). Does it make sense to parallelize this? If so, would using `parallelStream` be a good way to go? If I use parallelStream, I will create my own ForkJoinPool to better control the pool size. If not parallelStream, then would futures (like CompletableFutures) be a better way to go?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you asking? From the information you have provided I don’t see why you should want to make it parallel.

Comment: 1. If it already runs fast enough, don’t introduce extra complication just to make it still faster. 2. No one here can tell you whether it will speed up in your setup. You will have to make your own measurements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing list of size 2000 should not take much time, either you can use single stream like this

```
nodes.stream()
     .filter(r->r.has("id") && 
               !r.get("id").asText().equals(map.get(r.get("name").asText())))
     .map(r-> r.get("id").asText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or `parallelStream`, but parallel stream can consume all available processors during the execution

```
nodes.parallelStream()
     .filter(r->r.has("id") && 
               !r.get("id").asText().equals(map.get(r.get("name").asText())))
     .map(r-> r.get("id").asText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```